# Javascript: How to reference my expression the correct way with a switch statement?

Tags: javascript

I have written a small function that takes 4 skill buttons and puts them in the position of my choice. Example:

```
     function addSkillButton(name, position) {
            var x = document.createElement("button");
            var target = dom.el("buttonwrappers");
            x.textContent = name;
            x.setAttribute("id", name);
            x.setAttribute("class", "selection");
            target.insertBefore(x, target.children[position]);
     }
addSkillButton(swipe.name, 0);
addSkillButton(defend.name, 1);
addSkillButton(cure.name, 2);
addSkillButton(debuff.name, 3);
```

This works fine as is, but I thought to myself.. I am going to have 50+ skills that come and go as the game progresses. Instead of me manually entering '0-3' to place skill positions on the DOM, I already have a `skill object` that puts each skill in a category type. I'll just write a switch statement that will automatically target each position for me! So I came up with this:

```
 function addSkillButton(name) {
        var x = document.createElement("button");
        var target = dom.el("buttonwrappers");
        x.textContent = name;
        x.setAttribute("id", name);
        x.setAttribute("class", "selection");

        switch(skill.category){
            case "Attack": 
            target.insertBefore(x, target.children[0]);
            break;
            case "Defend": 
            target.insertBefore(x, target.children[1]);
            break;
            case "Healing": 
            target.insertBefore(x, target.children[2]);
            break;
            case "Debuff": 
            target.insertBefore(x, target.children[3]);
            break;
            default:
            console.log("Case Statement switched to default");
            console.log(skill.category);
        }
    }
```

The problem I am running into is that skill.category is `undefined`. Am I missing something in my switch statements expression? Here is the rest of the code.

SKILL OBJECT:

```
skill = {
    bio: function (name, tier, category, description){
        this.name = name;
        this.tier = tier;
        this.category = category;
        this.description = description;
    },  
    list: [swipe, deepcut, balancedstrike, fury]
}

New = Object.create;

swipe = New(skill),
deepcut = New(skill),
balancedstrike = New(skill),
fury = New(skill),
defend = New(skill),
cure = New(skill),
debuff = New(skill);

swipe.bio("Swipe", 1, "Attack", "Basic Attack");
deepcut.bio("Deep Cut", 2, "Attack", "Poison your enemy - ignoring armor");
balancedstrike.bio("Balanced Strike", 2, "Attack", "Gain some of your balance back");
fury.bio("Fury", 2, "Attack", "Target loses balance");
defend.bio("Defend", 1, "Defend", "Maintain your balance");
cure.bio("Cure", 1, "Healing", "Heal your HP");
debuff.bio("Debuff", 1, "Debuff", "Lower enemys strength");
```

Comment: Try `switch(this.skill.category)`

Comment: Maybe its happening somewhere else in your code, but it doesn't look like you pass `skill` to your `addSkillButton` function

Comment: I tried that Karol and got the following:
TypeError: this.skill is undefined

Comment: You don't initialize a `skill.category` anywhere

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing `object` in this function `addSkillButton` then you have to call `this.skill.category` in switch statement because `skill.category` is undefined by itself. Or try with `name.skill.category`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the whole object to `addSkillButton` instead of `name`. 
Besides :

You can use **Decorator** design pattern where you forward the call to another function instead of another switch-block .

Use the following pattern  :

```
 function addSkillButton(name) {
        var x = document.createElement("button");
        var target = dom.el("buttonwrappers");
        x.textContent = name;
        x.setAttribute("id", name);
        x.setAttribute("class", "selection");
        return addSkillButton[skill.category || '_default'](x,target);
    }
```

Then :

```
   addSkillButon._default=function(x,target){
                 console.log("Case Statement switched to default");
                 console.log(skill.category);
  }; 
  addSkillButon.Attack=function(x,target){
      target.insertBefore(x, target.children[0]);
  }
```

so on. ...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of using swipe.name in my function argument when calling it.. it was better to just use the entire object itself. Ex:

Was:

```
addSkillButton(swipe.name);
```

Now:

```
addSkillButton(swipe);
```

I am now referencing the entire object, instead of parts of it, so now I can use the object to relay the category.

```
 function addSkillButton(object) {
        var x = document.createElement("button");
        var target = dom.el("buttonwrappers");
        x.textContent = object.name;
        x.setAttribute("id", object.name);
        x.setAttribute("class", "selection");

        switch(object.category){
            case "Attack": 
            target.insertBefore(x, target.children[0]);
            break;
            case "Defend": 
            target.insertBefore(x, target.children[1]);
            break;
            case "Healing": 
            target.insertBefore(x, target.children[2]);
            break;
            case "Debuff": 
            target.insertBefore(x, target.children[3]);
            break;
            default:
            console.log("Case Statement switched to default");
            console.log(object.name);
        }
    }
```